# Transposing Data in SPSS

Tags: transpose, spss

I have a SPSS data file with only four variables (columns), that I'm trying to transpose. The original file looks like:

```
ItemID  StudentID  Score   Weight  
123     a1         1.0       1.0
123     a1         0.0       1.0
123     a2         1.0       1.0
124     a1         0.0       5.0
124     a2         1.0       5.0
```

and what I am trying to get would use StudentID as the identifier variable, but also create new variables based upon the ItemID. So the data above would be transposed into:

```
StudentID    score_123   weight_123   score_124   weight_124
a1           1.0         1.0          0.0         5.0   
a2           0.0         1.0          1.0         5.0
```

The syntax I've tried is:

```
SORT CASES BY StudentID ItemID. 
CASESTOVARS 
/ID=StudentID 
/INDEX=ItemID
/GROUPBY=INDEX 
/VIND ROOT=ind.
```

But this clearly fails because of the repeated measures in the data file; StudentID and ItemID are sometimes repeated. (As a side note, I have no other variables to work from).

Do I have to remove duplicate cases, or is there another way to achieve this? I'm reluctant to drop duplicates because I don't know which cases might matter (without other information, identifying duplicates as primary/last is arbitrary). The data file has several million cases, as well.

I'm using SPSS stats v. 24 with python installed. I also have access to R but have never used it.

Any help that can be passed along would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an additional variable to indicate duplicates, and add it to the `ID=` list in your `casestovars` command:

```
*this is just to recreate your example data.
data list free/StudentID (a4) ItemID  Score Weight (3f4)  .
begin data
a1  123 1   1
a1  123 0   1
a2  123 1   1
a1  124 0   5
a2  124 1   5
end data.
```

Now create the DUP variable which will be counting duplicates of (StudentID X ItemID) combination. The first occurrence will get value zero.

```
sort cases by StudentID ItemID.
compute dup=0.
if $casenum>1 and  lag(StudentID)= StudentID and lag(ItemID)=ItemID dup=lag(dup)+1.
```

Now adding DUP to the restructure command will get you to where you wanted:

```
sort cases by StudentID dup ItemID.
CASESTOVARS /ID=StudentID dup /INDEX=ItemID /GROUPBY=INDEX/sep="_".
```

Comment: That is brilliant! Thank you very much eli-k, it fixed my problem and the explanation was extremely helpful.